# Use an interactive shell under Make

Tags: make, gnu-make

I'm trying to use an interactive shell under Make.

Here's an example with Docker:

```
ubuntu:
  docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

This `ubuntu` target doesn't work well. For example, when I type I can't see the characters until I execute what I wrote.

Meanwhile, this work perfectly:

```
bash:
  bash
```

I spawn in a bash process, and I'm able to work seamlessly with it.

Why `bash` works while `docker run -it ubuntu bash` doesn't? And could I possibly make my `ubuntu` target work?

Comment: It works well for me with Bash 5.0.18 as sh, make 4.2.1 and 19.03.8

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk It seems to be caused by zsh. Because it does work from a "bash host".

Comment: But make uses /bin/sh to execute commands, right? What does it point to on your system?

Comment: /bin/sh points to the usual shell.

Comment: I don't know what's the *usual shell*. Dash? Bash? ZSH? mksh?

Comment: Sorry, it's dash. I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.1, and make 4.2.1

Comment: It looks like make doesn't run /bin/sh for everything because it works even after doing `sudo mv /bin/sh /bin/sh.bak` (do that in the virtual machine for safety)

Comment: Make seem to use the user's `$SHELL`. If I echo `$SHELL` in the make target, it points to `/usr/bin/zsh`

Comment: It really seems to be an issue with the host zsh. If I set the `SHELL` var in the Makefile to `/bin/sh`, I still have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was coming from [GRC](https://github.com/garabik/grc/)'s script (https://github.com/garabik/grc#zsh).

I found a related issue: https://github.com/garabik/grc/issues/82.

Until it's solved, I removed `make` from the `cmds` variable in `/etc/grc.zsh`.